# clang error while compiling template

Tags: c++, templates, clang, c++17, clang++

I am trying to touch C++17 features and I have selected clang. 
Here is simplified example of my code that could not be compiled via clang:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

template<
    typename T,
    template<typename T_> typename Final>
class Base
{
public:
    decltype(auto) Foo() const noexcept
    {
        using TFinal = Final<T>;
        auto& _this = static_cast<const TFinal&>(*this);
        return _this.Bar<true>();
    }
};

template<typename T>
class Derived :
    public Base<T, ::Derived>
{
public:
    template<bool min>
    T Bar() const noexcept
    {
        return min ?
            std::numeric_limits<T>::lowest() :
            std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Derived<int> instance;
    auto result = instance.Foo();
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It fails here:

```
return _this.Bar<true>();
```

and error message is:

```
main.cpp:14:32: error: expected expression
        return _this.Bar<true>();
                               ^
main.cpp:35:10: error: variable has incomplete type 'void'
    auto result = instance.Foo();
         ^
```

Here is how I am compiling it:

```
clang++-5.0 main.cpp -std=c++17
```

Some additional info. Visual Studio 17 with latest language version can eat this. When bar function is not template, everything is ok...

Any suggestions what is wrong here?

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be

```
return _this.template Bar<true>();
```

In your case `_this` has dependent type. To refer to its member templates you have to use the keyword `template` explicitly.

[Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: That works in this case, thanks.